# glassfish4 weld deployment exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DefinitionException

Tags: cdi, ejb-3.1, java-ee-7

I have remote ejb refs (in remote.jar)

```
 @Remote
    public interface UserManager{
      public void doSomething();
    }
```

Implementation in ejb.jar

```
 @Stateless
   public class UserManagerImpl implements UserManager{
     public void doSomething(){}
   }
```

//generally this is a local bean accessed only within the ejb jar
   //this actually an entity session bean

```
@Stateless
   public class CompanyFacade{
   }
```

CDI in war archive

```
   public class CDIProducer{
     @EJB
     @Produces
     UserManager usermanager;
   } 




 @Named
    @SessionScoped
    public class Controller implements Serializable{
       @Inject
       private UserManager userManager;
    }
```

This is my Error trace:

```
SEVERE:   Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI definition failure:The type of the injection point userManager is com.anosym.remote.ejb.manager.user.UserManager.  The type of the physical resource is com.anosym.ejb.facade.CompanyFacade They are incompatible. 
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DefinitionException: The type of the injection point userManager is com.anosym.remote.ejb.manager.user.UserManager.  The type of the physical resource is com.anosym.ejb.facade.CompanyFacade They are incompatible. 
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.throwProducerDefinitionExeption(InjectionServicesImpl.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.validateResourceClass(InjectionServicesImpl.java:280)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.validateEjbProducer(InjectionServicesImpl.java:204)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.registerInjectionTarget(InjectionServicesImpl.java:167)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.postProcessInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:119)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:102)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.<init>(ManagedBean.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.of(ManagedBean.java:84)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.createManagedBean(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:269)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.createClassBean(BeanDeployer.java:238)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.createClassBeans(BeanDeployer.java:202)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:265)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:495)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:213)
    ... 36 more
```

I am trying to deploy an ear archive, and it fails with this error:

It is somehow resolving remote references to the wrong implementations.

What am i doing wrong?

EDIT:

I have changed the producer fields to producer methods:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class CDIProducer{
  @EJB
  private UserManager userManager

  @Produces
  public UserManager getUserManager(){
    return userManager;
  }
}
```

At the point of injection, now i get a difference error:

```
SEVERE:   EJB5070: Exception creating stateless session bean : [CDIProducer]
WARNING:   EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB CDIProducer method: public com.anosym.remote.ejb.manager.user.UserManager com.anosym.web.CDIProducer.getUserManager()
WARNING:   javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:435)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2516)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1906)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy310.getUserManager(Unknown Source)
    at com.anosym.web.__EJB31_Generated__CDIProducer__Intf____Bean__.getUserManager(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:396)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:108)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:101)
    at com.anosym.web.CDIProducer$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.getUserManager(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstance(MethodInjectionPoint.java:86)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ProducerMethodProducer.produce(ProducerMethodProducer.java:97)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractMemberProducer.produce(AbstractMemberProducer.java:132)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:189)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:716)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:774)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:368)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:377)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector$1.proceed(DefaultInjector.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:142)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:91)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:158)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.ForwardingContextual.create(ForwardingContextual.java:27)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:103)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.PassivatingContextWrapper$AbstractPassivatingContextWrapper.get(PassivatingContextWrapper.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
    at com.anosym.controller.FeaturedController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getTop2ApprovedFeaturedAds(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getValue(UIRepeat.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getDataModel(UIRepeat.java:250)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.setIndex(UIRepeat.java:444)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.doVisitChildren(UIRepeat.java:679)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.visitTree(UIRepeat.java:637)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabView.visitTree(TabView.java:414)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ValidateComponentNesting.processEvent(ValidateComponentNesting.java:53)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(ComponentSystemEvent.java:118)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2187)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2163)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:303)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:739)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:739)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:994)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.doFilter(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:130)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:700)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:246)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:430)
    ... 113 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:514)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:97)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:698)
    ... 115 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=com.anosym.web.CDIProducer/userManager,Remote 3.x interface =com.anosym.remote.ejb.manager.user.UserManager resolved to intra-app EJB UserManagerImpl in module kataxi-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,ejb-link=kataxi-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar#UserManagerImpl,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.anosym.remote.ejb.manager.user.UserManager,refType=Session into class com.anosym.web.CDIProducer: Can not set com.anosym.remote.ejb.manager.user.UserManager field com.anosym.web.CDIProducer.userManager to com.anosym.remote.ejb.manager.user._UserManager_Wrapper
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.injectEJBInstance(JCDIServiceImpl.java:257)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.injectEjbInstance(BaseContainer.java:1683)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:475)
    ... 117 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=com.anosym.web.CDIProducer/userManager,Remote 3.x interface =com.anosym.remote.ejb.manager.user.UserManager resolved to intra-app EJB UserManagerImpl in module kataxi-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,ejb-link=kataxi-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar#UserManagerImpl,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.anosym.remote.ejb.manager.user.UserManager,refType=Session into class com.anosym.web.CDIProducer: Can not set com.anosym.remote.ejb.manager.user.UserManager field com.anosym.web.CDIProducer.userManager to com.anosym.remote.ejb.manager.user._UserManager_Wrapper
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:717)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:484)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:138)
    ... 123 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.anosym.remote.ejb.manager.user.UserManager field com.anosym.web.CDIProducer.userManager to com.anosym.remote.ejb.manager.user._UserManager_Wrapper
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:665)
    ... 126 more
```

I can forget about producers and simply inject the local bean CDIProducer as (on jboss as7 but not on glassfish):

```
@EJB
private CDIProducer producer;
```

and then use the injected remote ejbs as:

```
producer.getUserManagr().doSomething();
```

I was really hoping to avoid this last scenario.

```
Field Class loader: WebappClassLoader (delegate=false; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)

Injected Class loader: EarClassLoader : 
urlSet = [URLEntry : file:/programming/java-projects/anosym/app/app-ear/target/gfdeploy/app-ear/app-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT_jar/, URLEntry : file:/home/user/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated/ejb/app-ear/app-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT_jar, URLEntry : file:/programming/java-projects/anosym/app/app-ear/target/gfdeploy/app-ear/app-service-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT_jar/, URLEntry : file:/home/user/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated/ejb/app-ear/app-service-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT_jar]
doneCalled = false 
 Parent -> org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@75e246cc
```

Answer (score 0):

If your class is already an EJB, creating a producer method, or field, for it is redundant.  The EJB is already exposed and can be injected using `@Inject`.  Why do you think you need a producer method/field?

Comment: Try injecting remote ejb into cdi? You will always get NullPointerException

Comment: Based on your errors, it looks like you may have two implementations of this interface.  Is this accurate?  Did you try plugging in the remote JNDI name in the injection point?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the edit, i realized on the glassfish-web.xml, you need to set classloader delegate to true in order to use the earwide classloader, this will ensure that the interface is the same class (same class loader)

```
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>/</context-root>
  **<class-loader delegate="true"/>**
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```